# Get objects (highways) without it's relations (bus_stops) using overpass turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I try to get a list of all streets/addresses for a single *geocodeArea*. E.g.

```
{{geocodeArea:Heidelberg}}->.searchArea;
(
nwr[highway=highway][name](area.searchArea);
nwr[highway=living_street][name](area.searchArea);
nwr[highway=residential][name](area.searchArea);
nwr[highway=primary][name](area.searchArea);  
nwr[highway=secondary][name](area.searchArea);
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

With that, for the primary and secondary highways I also get bus_stop ([Node 3205201698](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/3205201698#map=19/49.41503/8.77265)) and tram_stops because they relate to the chosen highway type. I tried removing them with the difference operator but with no luck so far.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bus stop node 3205201698](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/3205201698) is part of the [highway 259359975](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/259359975). You can't remove it or otherwise your highway will have a gap.

In OSM the geometry of a [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) is defined by [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node). Both ways and nodes can have [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags). This means a node already being part of a highway can represent an additional object, such as a bus stop. Removing this *node* will remove part of the *way* geometry.

Comment: Alright, that I get. No doubt the bus_stop should be in relation to that highway. When I try to get only the names of certain highway types, how can I avoid getting the names of their related objects?

Comment: You could simplify your query. First, only search for ways since you aren't interested in nodes and relations: Replace `nwr` with `way`. Then, drop the recursion step (`(._;>;);`) if you only need highway names but not their geometry. This will lead to the following query: `{{geocodeArea:Heidelberg}}->.searchArea;(way[highway=highway][name](area.searchArea);way[highway=living_street][name](area.searchArea);way[highway=residential][name](area.searchArea);way[highway=primary][name](area.searchArea);  way[highway=secondary][name](area.searchArea););out;` (https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/QdJ).

Comment: Worked like a charm! I tried replacing _way_ by _nwr_ and removing the recursion step before, but also overpass suggested (when choosing a "visual output") reparing the data (= adding **(._;>;);** ). Since it didn't show anything without it, I fell for it... As a csv-output everything is fine.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It suggests to repair it because it isn't able to *show* (i.e. to *render*) ways if the corresponding nodes are missing. Nevertheless these ways are contained in the output, without their geometry.

Comment: Great, one more question: How can I limit my search with a geocodeArea and e.g. postal_code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer this question.